# sqrt() argument after * must be a sequence

Tags: python, function, parameters, arguments, typeerror

First of all, I'm super new to python and I actually search for my problem but the examples were to heavy to understand.

Here is my homework; I need a function which takes two functions as an argument and returns if the results of the two functions are same or not? Basically, it will give either TRUE of FALSE.

For that I wrote:

```
def f(x,y,z):
    k=x(*z)
    l=y(*z)
    return k == l
```

The previos code I wrote for single function was working but when I modified it for two function as above, it gives an error as following :

```
import math
>>> f(math.sqrt,math.cos,5)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#56>", line 1, in <module>
    f(math.sqrt,math.cos,5)
  File "D:/Users/karabulut-ug/Desktop/yalanmakinesi.py", line 2, in f
    k=x(*z)
TypeError: sqrt() argument after * must be a sequence
>>>
```

I could not figured it out since the error giving function is normally does not take a sequence. So I dont think it makes a sense :) Any help is appreciated.. Thanks :)

Comment: What do you think the splat operator `*` does in this context?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`z` is just a single number, but the `*` argument expansion syntax requires that you pass in a sequence (like a `list`, `tuple` or `str`, for example).

Either *remove* the `*` (and make your function work for just single arguments), or use `*z` in the function signature to make `z` a tuple of 0 or more captured arguments:

```
def f(x, y, z):
    k = x(z)
    l = y(z)
    return k == l
```

or

```
def f(x, y, *z):
    k = x(*z)
    l = y(*z)
    return k == l
```

The latter now works for functions with more than one argument too:

```
f(math.pow, math.log, 10, 10)
```

If you added a `**kw` argument to the signature, then keyword arguments could be handled too:

```
def f(x, y, *args, **kwargs):
    k = x(*args, **kwargs)
    l = y(*args, **kwargs)
    return k == l
```

Here I renamed `z` to `args` to better reflect its purpose.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax `*z` invokes [argument unpacking](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) on `z`. When `z` is just an integer, there is no iterator behavior defined, and so you see this error. Try:

```
>>> f(math.sqrt, math.cos, [5])
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `*`. Its for unpacking. So:

```
def f(x,y,z):
    k=x(z)
    l=y(z)
    return k == l
```

You use the `*` operator when you want to pass in an iterable object, like a `list` or `tuple` as something thats split up. So, for example:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

So, for an arbitrary function, `f`:

```
f(*a) = f(1,2,3,4,5)
```